# Launch page on second monitor does not maximize

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am working on 2 monitors and running Puppeteer tests.

I am using this code in order to open the browser on my 2nd monitor:

```
 const browser = await puppeteer.launch({

    args: ['--window-position=1920,0','--start-maximized',
     '--disable-web-security',
      '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process','--disable-infobars']});
```

The browser does open on my 2nd monitor, but it is Not maximized.

How to make it open in maximized mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding

--start-fullscreen

Did the trick.

Comment: Found this for extensive args that can be used: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/